# Overlaying an image without stretching the CSS row

Tags: css, image

I have a row that is 50px high, and I have an image 30px high (by 100px) that I want to put in that row (it's not a table, just a header row I've set up with bootstrap CSS).

But when I put `<img src="image.png" />` in the row, the row stretches to a height of 60px. This impacts the nav links I have there and makes things look out of alignment. Is there something I can put on the image, or some CSS magic, so it appears overlayed or in the background or something so it won't change the height of the row?

Thanks

CODE:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" id="header-logo" href="{{ path('homepage') }}"><img src="{{ asset('image.png') }}" /></a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Exit</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: A fiddle would be nice, but ummm.. those children of that row, like img and the nav container, make it `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align:middle` so they would be aligned. yay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see if the row has padding applied by bootstrap or maybe the image has inherited a margin that is pushing the container row height.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're on to something. It looks like the image is inheriting a padding which is causing it. If I add this CSS: `#header-logo { padding-top: 0 !important; padding-bottom: 0 !important; ... } ` then the row no longer stretches, but the image is top aligned instead of centre aligned. What can I do?

Comment: You can use `margin: 0px auto` to center an image in it's parent element. If you want a margin on top and beneath the image you can use `margin: 5px auto`, for example.

Comment: Thanks, I played around with margin as you suggested. If I use `margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px !important;` then for some reason I'm still getting a margin on the left and the right? Shouldn't that code be forcing no margin on the left and right?

Comment: Never mind, I got it by doing: `padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px !important; margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px !important;`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with `background-image`. `background-image` has a bunch of different attributes, which you can read about [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). I put together an example for your situation on [jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnFish/opv3rd0z/)

Comment: I don't think this will solve my problem, but I think I will find that useful in the future so I will give an up vote... thanks

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. You might want to change the width so it scales proportionally. I hope this helps!

```
<img src="image.png" height="40">
```